# How to disable cloud init networking?

Tags: cloud, cloud-init

I am trying to disable cloud init network configuration. From the cloud init doc, I have to set `network-config={config: disabled}` in the kernel command line entry.

When I set it in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="network-config={config: disabled}"
```

and run `update-grub` but it gives me the following error:

```
generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-104-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-104-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
Syntax error at line 128
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
```

Looks like it doesn't take a yaml string.

Am I configuring in the right place?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Create a file at `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-custom-networking.cfg` which contains :

```
network: {config: disabled}
```